# Google Play Services - Could not find dependency

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, google-play-services

I'm building an app for the first time, it worked well with Google Map but a problem appeared when i added Firebase to my app.
I change some dependencies and this error occured after syncing with Gradle file :

> Failed to resolve: com.google.android.gms:play-services:15.0.1
>
> Install Repository and sync project
>
> Show in File
>
> Show in Project Structure dialog

Obviously i tried to click on **Install Repository and sync project**. During the installation, another error occured :

> Could not find dependency "com.google.android.gms:play-services:15.0.1"

Here is my dependencies in build.gradle file. As you can see, i didn't forget to use **implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:15.0.1'**.

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha3'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0-alpha3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

I found people with the same problem and i tried lots of proposed solutions, but the problem isn't solved.

Comment: Have you added `google()` in repo list for you project dependency and hopefully you're using updated `google-services plugin` in buildscript dependency

Comment: As Aryan write, be sure to review https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup

Comment: I added my build.gradle project file as an answer. I'm going to visit https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup again, i did it yesterday and days before...

Answer (score -1):

You can see below my build.gradle project file.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0-alpha03'
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}
task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```